# Using Red and Blue values to colour a pixel (BufferedImage)?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I got the red and blue values of a `pixel` from `get.RGB` and using `bitwise` operators:

```
            red = (rgb[i][j] >> 8) & 0xFF;
            blue = rgb[i][j] & 0xFF;
```

But how do I recolour the pixel in question with the "average of red and blue values"?

This means I have to exclude the green.

The only required import is BufferedImage.

Comment: The average of 2 scalars is a scalar, so I don't understand how you can update a vector (in colorspace) to a scalar.

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now is that the OP wants a grey pixel, with all colors set to the same value. That value being the average of red and blue former values. But that's only a guess of course...

Comment: I want to average the red and blue values for a given RGB value in a pixel. Without the green, sorry if I am confusing its cause I am confused. I have retrieved the RGB value of a pixel throughout .getRGB but I don't know how to manipulate this to turn a coloured (RGB) picture into a purply picture (RB)

Comment: Well, on SO we can help you overcome difficulties to achieve what to want. However, I'm afraid we can't find what *you* want for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is really unclear. Ask your teacher what it is you are trying to achieve and then maybe we can help doing so. Here are some elements that can help you.

#### Get red, green and blue for an RGB number

You got the first part almost right. Remember the colors returned by `getRGB()` are on 8 bits each, so here is how to get them:

```
int red = (rgb[i][j] >> 16) & 0xFF; 
int green = (rgb[i][j] >> 8) & 0xFF;
int blue = rgb[i][j] & 0xFF;
```

#### Build an RGB number from red, green and blue values

If your problem is how to recombine rgb colors into one number, here is how to do that:

```
pixelColor = (red << 16) + (green << 8) + blue
```

#### Doing what you want with it

The average of red and blue is really obvious, this is the formula you pointed out:

```
int average = (red + blue) / 2;
```

If what you want is a purple pixel using the average of red and green, then you just have to set red and blue to the average value, and green to 0:

```
int pixelColor = (average << 16) + average // using average for red and blue, and 0 for green
```

EDIT: Seems that you don't want to take out the green after all.

```
int pixelColor = (average << 16) + (green << 8) + average // using average for red and blue, and keep the green unchanged
```

EDIT: Or maybe you want the green to take the average of red and blue?

```
int pixelColor = (red << 16) + (average << 8) + blue; // keep red and bllue, and put their average as the green color
```

Comment: how do i compute the average? just (red+blue)/2? how do i ignore the green value?

Comment: `(red+blue)/2` sounds good for an arithmetic average. I don't know what you're asked on this aspect, but I imagine you have to get a grey pixel, with the value set to this average, am I right? You're not clear about what you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I need to turn a coloured picture into a purply picture some how and I am told I need to average the values of red and blue without the green?

Comment: My question is how do I get this average in RGB values to setRGB?

Comment: I managed to get a picture cyan blue, but it doesn't have some of the other colours that is in the picture like some yellows :S

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought you had the first part right, but actually it's 8 bit per color. So you'll have to change the shift numbers (I edited)

Comment: but it shows the whole picture to be a purply colour, I need the original colours to kinda show through a little over the purply background

Comment: so overall it needs to be purple but with the original colours showing through, :S

Comment: that's what it should do here, maybe you don't want to take out the green totally then, and you just want to set the red and green to the same level. you're really not clear about what you want! This is a forum to help solve technical difficulties, we're not supposed to guess what you might want to achieve... You should really ask your questions to the teacher that wrote the assignment. I edited my post.